# requests_with_caching is throwing 'Response not interpretable as json' for a specific input of 'Deadpool 2'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
import requests_with_caching
import json

def get_movie_data(movie):
    baseurl= "http://www.omdbapi.com/"
    d = {}
    d["t"] = movie
    d["r"] = "json"
    data = requests_with_caching.get(baseurl, params = d)
    jsonData = data.json()
    return jsonData


def get_movie_rating(movies):
    print(movies['Ratings'])
    for item in movies["Ratings"]:
        print(item['Value'])
```

It returns KeyValueError : Ratings is not defined. This happens to all of inputs except "Venom". The url is being created correctly for all inputs.

Comment: This means that the json returned does not have a `Ratings` key for some results. Websites are not required to return consistently results, I would guess this is your issue. You can check if this key exists before trying to access it.

Comment: http://www.omdbapi.com/?r=json&t=Deadpool+2&apikey=9cf687b5

Comment: this is the json data generated and it contains the Ratings key

Comment: There's no reason that data shouldn't work. Which data is failing?

Comment: For "Deadpool 2"

Comment: I just tried your code with that url and it worked. You're passing the api key as well?

Comment: Yes I tried with apiKey, without the key. When I use "Venom" it works totally fine with and without the key. It shows KeyError for Deadpool 2

Comment: Try using `return json.loads(data)` instead of calling `.json()` on data itself. I'm not familiar with `requests_with_caching` but it could be an issue with parsing the json. I tried it with the regular requests module and it works fine.

Comment: sure I'll try it!! Thanks